# segfault with linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am having trouble with linked lists in C, I have only done data structures such as this in c++.

Gdb is giving me a

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804a23c in addArg (base=0x1, argument=0x804e410 "is") at myshell.c:42
42          while ( (curr != NULL) && (curr->n != NULL) )`

I am familiar with segmentation faults having to do with memory, however I thought I have allocated memory correctly. What am I doing wrong?

addArg is being called as `addArg(currentCmd->args, lexeme);`and currentCmd is a pointer to a node struct

```
struct lnode {
 char *x;
 struct lnode *n;
};


struct node
  {
    char *command;
    struct lnode *args;
    int input;
    int output;
    int error;
    char *in;
    char *out;
    char *err;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
  };



void addArg(struct lnode *base, char *argument)
 {
 struct lnode *curr = base;

//this is line 42
  while ( (curr != NULL) && (curr->n != NULL) )
    curr = curr->n;

   curr -> n = malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
   curr = curr->n;
   curr->x = strdup(argument);
   curr->n = NULL;
 }




struct node* createNode(char *command_, int input_, int output_, int error_, char *in_, char *out_, char *err_, struct node *prev_)
  {
  struct node *n;
  n = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
  n->command = strdup(command_);
  n->prev = prev_;
  n->next = NULL;
  n->input = input_;
  n->output = output_;
  n->error = error_;
  n->in = in_;
  n->out = out_;
  n->err = err_;
  n->args=malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));

 return n;
  }
```

Comment: I changed my answer to a comment instead since it's not likely the cause of _this_ problem. After the `while`-loop `curr` might be `NULL` but you try to set a member of it, that will result in problems later on. Make sure you fix that or you'll be back here soon again ;-) (Clarification: Send a NULL-pointer as argument to that function and you'll end up with a nice SIGSEGV signal :)

Comment: It is my understanding that curr points to the argument that is passed into the function with points to a 'lnode args' member in a node struct.

Comment: Well if your `base` argument to the `addArg` function is `NULL`, then you are going to segfault. In this case the problem is most likely as John Kugelman says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by making the `lnode *args`  into `lnode args` and making the required changes to memory managment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `currentCmd->args` is an invalid pointer. Perhaps a pointer to `free()`d memory. Or an uninitialized pointer, or a pointer to a local variable that's gone out of scope (though these latter two don't appear to be the case here).

Or perhaps you've accidentally overwritten out-of-bounds memory somewhere else in your program. Pointer issues aren't always at the point of failure; sometimes they're in earlier code, unrelated code even.

Comment: I edited the code to initialize  args in the node struct, to NULL after allocating memory, but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What i can see from your gdb output, the problem with `while ( (curr != NULL) && (curr->n != NULL) )` is that if curr == NULL you are still trying to access curr->n to compare, so you should change that condition to only compare curr, and handle curr->n only if curr is not null, maybe breaking the cicle inmediatly if curr->n == NULL.